# Probability of birthdays of thirty people

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

Given thirty people, how to find the probability that among twelve months there are six months containing two birthdays and another six containing three birthdays.

Solution:- Solution given is $\left(\frac{30!}{2^6*6^6}\binom{12}{6}\right)*12^{-30}$

I agree that total sample space is $12^{30}$ and any six months can be selected out of twelve months in $\binom{12}{6}$ ways. I didn't understand this figure$\frac{30!}{(2^6)*(6^6)}$. What is the author's logical thinking behind it?

Comment: "there are six months containing two birthdays and another six containing three **months**." should that last one be "three birthdays" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to get that figure.

To identify one of the ways the $30$ people can have birthdays satisfying the question's conditions, out of the $12^{30}$ possible ways the $30$ people can have their birthdays distributed among the $12$ months,
it is not enough to identify which of the months have two birthdays and which have three.
It also matters *which* two people have birthdays in the first two-birthday month, which have birthdays in the second, and so forth.

If we were to enumerate all those possible combinations, we would have
$\binom{30}{2}$ ways to choose who is born in the first two-birthday month.
That leaves $28$ people yet to be assigned, and $\binom{28}{2}$ ways to choose who is born in the second two-birthday month.
Note that
$$\binom{30}{2} \binom{28}{2} = \frac{30!}{2!28!}  \frac{28!}{2!26!} 
= \frac{30!}{2! 2! 26!}.$$
So we get some cancellation when we expand the binomial coefficients to factorials.
The next factor, $\binom{26}{2},$ will cancel the $26!$ in the denominator, and so forth, and in the end (after running through all the two-birthday months and three-birthday months) you have
$$ \frac{30!}{2! 2! 2! 2! 2! 2! 3! 3! 3! 3! 3! 3!} = \frac{30!}{2^6 6^6}.$$

Alternatively, using multinomials, the number of ways to distribute $30$ distinguishable people into a sequence of six groups of two and six groups of three
(the groups all having unique identities, in this case month names, but the sequence of individuals within a group not being considered), is
$$ \binom{30}{2\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 3\ 3\ 3\ 3\ 3\ 3}
=\frac{30!}{2! 2! 2! 2! 2! 2! 3! 3! 3! 3! 3! 3!},$$
same as before.
(In fact I would take the previous argument as an intuition for the multinomial formula, though further proof is required to make the formula general.)

---

A slightly faster way to get the result if you're not already familiar with multinomials:
to distribute the $30$ birthdays among the twelve months,
we line the $30$ people up in a row according to the order of their birthdays.
This gives $30!$ ways to distribute the birthdays, but since we did not respect the order of birth within the month when we came up with the $12^{30}$-element sample space,
we have overcounted each actual element of the sample space by a factor of $2!$ for each two-birthday month (since we separately counted both ways those birthdays could occur) and a factor of $3!$ for each three-birthday month,
so we have to divide by $2!$ six times and by $3!$ six times to get back to the correct number.

This is similar to an argument you could have made for "$n$ choose $k$" formula,
except that we have more than two groups into which we are partitioning the $n$ items.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thanks for finding those errata. I think they're correct now.

Comment: They are, as far as a I can see.

Answer (score 2):

First find the probability that there are $2$ birthdays in each of the first $6$ months and there are $3$ birthdays in each of the other months.

The probability on that event is:$$\frac{30!}{2!^63!^6}\left(\frac1{12}\right)^2\cdots\left(\frac1{12}\right)^2\left(\frac1{12}\right)^3\cdots\left(\frac1{12}\right)^3=\frac{30!}{2!^63!^6}12^{-30}$$

This is multinomial distribution (actual $12$-nomial distribution with $12$ equal parameters).

Now realize that there are $\binom{12}6$ different choices for the $6$ months having $2$ birthdays.

This leads to probability: $$\binom{12}6\frac{30!}{2!^63!^6}12^{-30}$$